# AngularJS: access directive data from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Lets assume I have a AngularJS directive looking like this:

```
app.directive('psDIR', [
    function() {
        return {
            template: "<div style='padding: 5px; border: 1px solid red; margin-bottom: 10px;'><p>This is a direcive:</p> <textarea rows='5' cols='50' ng-model='md'></textarea></div>",
            restrict: 'AEC',
            scope: {}
        }
    }
]);
```

I am using this directive number of times on a single page. How do I get a value  of every directive instance/scope of the `ng-model="md"` in my `MainCtrl` (i.e. I want to save this value in the `add()`) :

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        console.log("init");
        $scope.add = function() {
            console.log($scope);
        }
    }
]);
```

Plunker demo: http://embed.plnkr.co/Q5bw6CBxPYeNe7q6vPsk/preview

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are creating isolated scope and otherwise too you cannot access the child scope from parent scope.

The way out it to pass the model as parameter from parent like

`<div class="psDIR" model='field2'></div>
 <div class="psDIR" model='field1'></div>`

Then in the directive update them with attribute binding. See update plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/GKZHSDe5J0eCzqlgaf4g?p=preview

Comment: It is first time I see the model on the directive. Can you please provide me with a link maybe where I could do some more reading. many thanks

Comment: This is a random name that i took. You can take any name. Read compile documentation for directive api http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: This solution looks cleanest. Let me do some experimenting.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is with `require`:

```
app.directive('psDIR', [
    function() {
        return {
            ...,
            require: "ngController",
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngCtrl) {
              ngCtrl.hook(scope);
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

And the necessary change to the controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        console.log("init");
        $scope.add = function() {
            var i;
            for( i=0; i < psDirs.length; i++ ) {
              console.log(i + " -> " + psDirs[i].md);
            }
        }

        var psDirs = [];
        this.hook = function(scope) {
          psDirs.push(scope);
        };
    }
]);
```

Try it out here: http://plnkr.co/edit/zCZ1TOm3aK8V4piCAY6u?p=preview

---

If you do decide to go with this solution, I'd suggest implementing the "wrapper" controller in a specialized wrapper directive, so as to avoid situations where `ng-controller` may be set in some other element in the hierarchy. In this case, just `require: "wrapperDirective"`.

EDIT: The HTML for the wrapper directive case would simply look like:

```
<div wrapper-directive>
    <div class="psDIR"></div>
    <div class="psDIR"></div>
    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
</div>
```

And the directive itself uses the code of the previous `ng-controller`:

```
app.directive('wrapperDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        // YOU MAY WANT ISOLATED SCOPE, JUST ADD scope: {},
        controller: ["$scope", function($scope) {
            // SAME CODE AS BEFORE
            console.log("init");
            $scope.add = function() {
                var i;
                for( i=0; i < psDirs.length; i++ ) {
                  console.log(i + " -> " + psDirs[i].md);
                }
            }

            var psDirs = [];
            this.hook = function(scope) {
              psDirs.push(scope);
            };
        }]
    };
});
```

And of course change the `require` configuration:

```
app.directive('psDIR', [
    ...
    require: "^wrapperDirective",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, wrapperDirectiveCtrl) {
        wrapperDirectiveCtrl.hook(scope);
    }
```

Comment: Please can you go into more details about wrapper controller?

Comment: where is the `wrapperDirectiveCtrl` comming from?

Comment: It is the controller of `wrapperDirective`.

Comment: you mean the `controller` within the directive? Is this the name convention I should be using?

Comment: This is *a* naming convention. The critival is in the `require: "XXX"`, where `XXX` must match the name of the directive.

Comment: Many thanks, so after requiring the directive, the 4th argument of the link becomes the controller of this required directory & I can call the the argument whatever I wish?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Additionally you can require many controllers. And I have a mistake in the syntax above, the correct is `require: "^wrapperDirective"` (meaning search my parents for the named directive) - I will correct it in the answer. Read details [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

Comment: Many thanks for your time. Would you recommend an book on AngularJS or just docs?

Comment: Hi again. Books about programming tend to become obsolete really fast. Especially with Angular and the speed of its releases. So yeah, docs + source code (whenever needed) is my way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the right thing to do when you want to communicate between scopes (i.e. directives and other controllers) is to use a service.

You can take a look at a simple plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/8Al31Bq9BfoazUCpqhWy?p=preview

The `psDirs` service keeps a registry of the directives:

```
app.service('psDirs', function() {
  var psDirs = {
    dirs: [],
    register: function (dir) {
      psDirs.dirs.push(dir);
    }
  };

  return psDirs;
});
```

And the directives register themselves and update the value when they change:

```
link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
  var dir = { val: "" };
  psDirs.register(dir);

  scope.$watch('md', function (n, o) {
    if (n !== o) {
      dir.val = n;
    }
  });
}
```

Then your controller can inject the psDirs service and access the directive registry as needed. This prevents brittle scope relationships, and allows the the directive registry service to be used elsewhere, in multiple controllers and sections of your application.

Comment: This solution clearly works and it is easy t understand. However I cannot help myself to think that AngularJS team have seen this situation and they implemented this situation - I am just not aware of it!:)

Comment: Keeping state like this in services is generally a bad idea IMO - and has to be done carefully if at all. For example, your code above never unregisters the directive data from the service, meaning that it never gets garbage collected and over time the service will accumulate more and more redundant data as directives are destroyed and recreated. As well as the risk of your application unintentionally re-using "dead" data, if you happen to register anything that includes a closure you could end up with quite a significant memory leak!